# Mostrar Valor em Json + Mysql + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

Preciso fazer isso, mas vindo do banco de dados.... não sei como fazer

```
function decodificar($id)
{
if ($id == '1') {
    return json_encode(
        array(
            'id' => '1',
            'desc' => 'descricao do produto',
            'valor' => '49,90',
            'img' => 'img300x300.png',
            )
        );

} else if ($id == '2') {
    return json_encode(
        array(
            'id' => '2',
            'desc' => 'descricao do produto',
            'valor' => '94,90',
            'img' => 'img300x300.png',
            )
        );

}
```

Estou fazendo isso mas nao da certo

```
$pdo = db_connect();
$listar = $pdo->prepare("SELECT curso_id, curso_descricao, curso_preco, curso_foto FROM cursos WHERE ativo = 1");
$listar->execute();

function decodificar($id)
{
while ($dados = $listar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if ($id == $dados['curso_id']) {
    return json_encode(
        array(
            'id' => $dados['curso_id'],
            'desc' => $dados['curso_descricao'],
            'valor' => $dados['curso_preco'],
            'img' => $dados['curso_foto'],
            )
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: Faz a leitura dos dados e retorna na estrutura que você quer. Um ótimo ponto de partida: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysql.php

Comment: eu sei puxar. nao sei montar a estrutura, em questao do if e else if

Comment: Dá um var_dump no listar para ver o que retorna

Comment: Para aparecer em JSON é só passar um echo json_encode($array); não tem segredo. O que está dando errado?

Comment: @VitorPresutti ele nao retorna nada

Comment: @adventistaam - resultado - object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(85) "SELECT curso_id, curso_descricao, curso_preco, curso_foto FROM cursos WHERE ativo = 1" }

Comment: Não dê o return dentro do while, primeiro alimente o vetor e no final, após o if dê o `echo json_encode`

Comment: Ao invés de fetchAll coloque fetch

Comment: @adventistaam a página fica em branco... não retorna nada

Comment: O que vê fez? Lembre-se que neste caso você está apenas dando um return e não echo,

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83277/discussion-between-betinho-silva-and-adventistaam).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode primeiro alimentar o vetor e depois retornar ou exibir o vetor

Exemplo:

```
function decodificar($id)
{
     $arrRetorno = array();
     while ($dados = $listar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
              if ($id == $dados['curso_id']) {
                  $arrRetorno[] = array(
                     'id' => $dados['curso_id'],
                     'desc' => $dados['curso_descricao'],
                     'valor' => $dados['curso_preco'],
                     'img' => $dados['curso_foto'],
                   );
               } //end of if
         } // end of while
      return json_encode($arrRetorno);
 }
```

Nesse caso irá apenas retornar.

Caso você queira exibir o retorno você pode dar um `echo`.

Exemplo substituir :

```
return json_encode($arrRetorno);
```

por

```
echo json_encode($arrRetorno);
```

Answer (score 0):

O último item do array não pode conter vírgula. Acredito que este seja o erro. Tente remover a vírgula no fim de `'img' => 'img300x300.png'` e nos diga o que acontece.